# How to solve AmbiguousMatchException: The request matched multiple endpoints?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, model-view-controller

I have following methods in my controller.

```
[Route("pdf-to-word-converter")]
public IActionResult Index()
{
    //-code
}

[Route("pdf-to-word-converter")]
public async Task<IActionResult> Index(ToolModel model)
{
    //Code-------
}

[Route("pdf-to-word-converter")]
public async Task<IActionResult> Download(ToolModel model)
{
    //-code
}
```

Now when I try to execute the app following error occurs.

> AmbiguousMatchException: The request matched multiple endpoints.
> Matches:
>
> OnlineToolSpot.Controllers.PdfToWordController.Index (ToolSpot)
> OnlineToolSpot.Controllers.PdfToWordController.Index (ToolSpot)
> OnlineToolSpot.Controllers.PdfToWordController.Download (ToolSpot)

How to solve this. I am a beginner.

Comment: Use different routes and HTTP method.

Comment: @YongShun Can you demonstrate please?

Comment: use HTTP methods like `GET` `PUT` `POST` or use a different routing path like @yong-shun mentioned

Comment: This is because all routes in MVC are GET by default. You are also using the same pattern "pdf-to-word-converter" for all 3 routes so MVC doesn't know which one to pick. See this document on how to use a pattern route since it looks like you want the same base route but different MVC actions based on what is supplied in the query string. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/routing?view=aspnetcore-7.0

If your intent is to post, then change the second and third actions to HttpPost and implement a new route name for one of the posted actions.

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to solve your problem, right now, what I can do, is to guide you to the best solution.

One way to solve your issue is changing your Htpp method, as mentioned by @YongShun.

```
[HttpGet("pdf-to-word-converter")]
public IActionResult Index()
{
    //-code
}

[HttpPost("pdf-to-word-converter")]
public async Task<IActionResult> Index(ToolModel model)
{
    //Code-------
}

[HttpPut("pdf-to-word-converter")]
public async Task<IActionResult> Download(ToolModel model)
{
    //-code
}
```

But there is no way to know for sure that those Htpp method are the right ones using Restfull achitecture. You could read more about those methods [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods) and read about how to resolve ambiguous actions [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/routing?view=aspnetcore-7.0#resolving-ambiguous-actions) (same link as @2189490 mentioned)